# What is the most robust way to parse domain and username from a user string in vbscript

Tags: windows, script, windows-domain, vbscript, wmi

The user can input a string, so basically 4 options:

1. username
2. .\username
3. localcomputername\username
4. remotedomain.com\username

What is the most robust way to return the domain and username given that input string in vbs?

So for the 4 input strings above, here are the outputs:

1. domain = "localcomputername", usernme = "username"
2. domain = "localcomputername", usernme = "username"
3. domain = "localcomputername", usernme = "username"
4. domain = "remotedomain.com", usernme = "username"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it in a two phases:
First split the input in a username and a password with a regular expression

```
Option Explicit

dim re, matches, match, test

Set re = new regexp
re.pattern = "^((.*)\\)?(.*)$"

for each test in array( _
    "username", _
    ".\username", _
    "localcomputername\username", _
    "remotedomain.com\username")

    Set matches = re.Execute(test)
    for each match in matches
        msgbox "domain: " & match.submatches(1) & vbNewLine & _
                "username: " & match.submatches(2)
    next
next
```

Then, Use a Select Case to make the domainname valid:

```
dim localhost, testdomain, outputDomain

localhost = "192.168.0.1"
for each testDomain in array( _
    ".", _
    localhost, _
    "", _
    "remotedomain.com")

    select case testDomain
        case localhost, "", "."
            outputDomain = localhost
        case else
            outputDomain = testDomain
    End Select

    msgbox testDomain & " becomes " & outputDomain
Next
```

Combine these two and you have your script to get the domain and username.
Disclaimer: The above code is tested examplecode, but you have to adapt it to your specific situation.